# IntentService pending intent using Alarm Manager not triggering?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a service defined as below :

```
    public class TestService extends IntentService {

        private static final String TAG = TestService.class.getSimpleName();

     public TestService() {
            super(TAG);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
                Logger.e(TAG, "Shoot !!! at : " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

private static PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestService.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(context, INTENT_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
    }
```

Manifest declaration :

```
<service
            android:name="com.testapp.service.TestService"
            android:exported="true"></service>
```

Alarm set in main activity using below method :

```
public static void setNextAlarm(Context context) {
            long triggerTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 120000l;
            Logger.e(TAG, "Next trigger time : " + new Date(triggerTime).toString());
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent pi = TestService.getPendingIntent(context);
            am.cancel(pi);
            am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    triggerTime, pi);
    }
```

When I see in logs or debug the "Next trigger time : " message shows proper two minutes later time than the current time. But onHandleIntent is never triggered i.e. not actually running the service. Few StackOverflow threads suggested having the fully qualified class name in manifest also recommended to set `android:exported="true"` which I did but not working. What may go wrong ?

Comment: An `ELAPSED_REALTIME*` alarm is based on the time since boot. `System.currentTimeMillis()` is based on the epoch. Your alarm is set _waaay_ in the future. Either change to an `RTC*` alarm, or figure the time with `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`

Comment: @MikeM. your absolutely right now I am using RTC_WAKEUP instead of ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP working for me please add an answer I will accept it as the solution, Thanks.

Comment: Ah, cool. I've actually answered this same problem before, so I'll just mark this as a duplicate. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. should I delete or vote close this question then, let me know?

Comment: Nah, you don't need to. Duplicates allow a broader set of search terms to land users on the correct solutions. Your post should just make it easier for people with the same issue to find the answer in the future. Of course, you're under no obligation to keep it, if you really don't want to.